# A 'name' attribute is required for <color>

Tags: adt

This error keeps on poping up in my code:

```
<resources
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <string name="app_name">Commen Games</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <color android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    <color android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/color1" />
    <string name="action_settings" tools:ignore="DuplicateDefinition">TODO</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: Haven't you tried putting a `name` at the `color` tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<color name="black">#000000</color>
```

Is an example of how you create a color in your strings.xml in your values folder. You can then reference the color in your xml layouts by using "@color/black". What you are doing here is completely wrong. I suggest you do some more tutorials in android development.

Comment: Thank you its just im trying to learn this coding stuff and its pretty hard. but thanks anyways!

Comment: Keep learning, I encourage that. Just try following some basic tutorials first like this one https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html?hl=p